# (N) neutral position automatic transmission?

Tags: automatic-transmission, hyundai

Hello everyone   I just want to say that my pleasure to be member here
My name is Hani I am from Egypt my car is a 2016 hyundai i30 2.0  (AT)

OK my topic is about neutral position 'N' ( AT )
Before I carry on I will just tell you that ( my Hyundai i30 allows you to pull the key from ignition without putting the shift on Park "P" it's weird I know.

Last month for first time because I was in hurry emergency. I shutdown the car with the gearshift in "N" and got back to car after 2 days and started it up normally, then I noticed the shifter was in neutral "N".

So I was afraid and started to search on Google 
Some said :-

1st / N & P are the same and they are the only option that allow you start up the car .
(is that true information ?)

2ND -/ Don't start up the car in N because once you do that there's friction between engine and transmission which will damage them in time 
(is that true information ?)

3rd - / N & D are same when come to oil pump. It will push the oil once the engine running  the only position that the oil pump is semi-stop is on Park "P"
(is that true information ?)

So as you see there's many opinions that make me confused and more worried

So  what I need to know  from  Mechanical Specialist or any one have knowledge about automatic transmission 
Could you tell me please : 
"Dose turning off or starting up the car in neutral  ['N']  cause any damage to mechanical or electronic parts" ?

Comment: There are many questions about this on this site that can be found with a search, here is just one : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/21735/10976

Answer (score 2):

Automatic car engines can only be started in Park or Neutral, the reason they can be started in neutral is so that you can restart the engine while the car is in motion. You can stop your engine while in neutral so you can shut down a problem engine and still roll to a stop safely.

There's nothing wrong with stopping or starting your engine in neutral instead of park, you won't cause damage to any component. Starting your car in Neutral instead of Park makes no difference.

The gear you are in makes no difference to the oil pump, it's driven by the engine. If the engine's running so is the oil pump.

Comment: Thank you for your help  so as I understand your reply  the neutral N  pisstion is safe to start up the car on it and will not cause any damage  right? ?  Because I am about to go to the dealership since my car still under warranty  so do I need to go or it's OK no problem happen  ??

Comment: What do you mean Neutral N pisstion, do you mean position? If that's what you mean then there's no reason to take your car in, starting in neutral is fine.

Comment: Sorry for late reply  yeh I mean position  (shifter was selected to N when start up )and it was parked 2 days before and the shifter on N  with hand brake  applied

Comment: There's no issue whatsoever from that @SamIhakim

Comment: Thank you for your  help now I am not worry any more